# Parallel processing of files in java with ExecutorService does not use all of the CPU power

Tags: java, performance, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a directory which contains 1000s of csv files that I need to parse. I have implemented the ExecutorService class of Java to do the job, wherein I assign each thread a csv file to parse. I have 4 cores in my machine. I do get some efficiency as compared to a single-threaded application. However, when I see the CPU utilization( using the task manager) it doesn't seem to be utilising all of the CPU power, the % of CPU used is just about 30%-40%. 
I just wanted to know if my approach is correct.

```
File dir = new File(file);
if(dir.isDirectory()){
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

for(File f : files){
    String file_abs_path = f.getAbsolutePath();
    int index = file_abs_path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    file_name = file_abs_path.substring(index);
    futuresList.add(eservice.submit(new MyParser(file_abs_path)));
}

Object gpDocs;
for(Future<List<MyObj>> future:futuresList) {
try {
    docs = future.get();
    arrayList = (List<MyObj>)docs;
    Iterator<MyObj> it = arrayList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
    doc = createDocument(file_name,it.next());
    try{
        //somefunction(doc);
        }catch(Exception e){}
}}catch (InterruptedException e) {}
catch (ExecutionException e) {}
}}
```

I am just wondering if my approach is correct? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

The code for the parser is :

```
public List<MyObj> call(){
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<MyObj> strat = 
new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<MyObj>();
strat.setType(MyObj.class);
String[] columns = new String[] {//list of columns in the csv file}; 

strat.setColumnMapping(columns);
CsvToBean<MyObj> csv = new CsvToBean<MyObj>();
BufferedReader reader = null;
String doc_line = "";
String[] docs;
String doc = "";
File dir = new File(file_path);
try{
    int comma_count = 0;
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir));
    while((doc_line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        docs = doc_line.split(",");
    doc += docs[i] + " ";
    }
    reader.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {/*e.printStackTrace();*/}
    return(csv.parse(strat,new StringReader(doc)));
}
```

Comment: 1. How do you create ExecutorService?
2. How big are these files? It maybe very well I/O bound task, not CPU bound. 3. Could you please show us all the code (not just the sketch)?

Comment: Your task is probably IO bound, and too many threads may actually decrease the IO if it forces the hard drive head to jump back and forth between files.

Comment: The dir size is about 500MB and each file should be around 2-3 MB. The code that I am using to create the ExecutorService is               int noProcs= Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService eservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noProcs);

Comment: Show your code for `MyPraser`

Comment: I do hope `doc = createDocument(file_name,it.next())` is not the actual parsing -- otherwise you do it all in one thread. How is the `MyParser(String file_abs_path)` implemented?

Comment: No, create document is basically just setting the properties. I did not understand what you meant by "_you do it all in one thread_" as I submit a new task for every file in the directory. **MyParser** is just a simple CSV file parser using opencsv that implements the Callable interface  and has the parsing logic in the call method that it overrides.

Comment: @dehsams123 we're talking about sketch. It's impractical. Show us your code. Don't be afraid. We don't bite :)

Comment: you thin if you run 1000 thread at same time, you will face with 100% of cpu? no this is possible of IO interaction, I suggest you decrease the number of concurrent threads, [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool) may help you

Answer (score 1):

As commented, your task is most likely IO bound, as most tasks involving IO to hard-drive generally are.

The best performance you can hope for is most likely to decouple the reading threads from the processing.  Probably, a single reading thread, reading blocks of data as large as possible and feeding it into a queue for processing will yield the best overall throughput.  The number of processing threads would just be whatever is necessary to keep up with the reading.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I see the CPU utilization( using the task manager) it
>   doesn't seem to be utilising all of the CPU power, the % of CPU used
>   is just about 30%-40%

This is because, you are processing the `files` sequentially rather than parallel. See the following block of code:

```
for(Future<List<MyObj>> future:futuresList) {
try {
    docs = future.get(); //(1)
    arrayList = (List<MyObj>)docs;//(2)
```

Line (1) is the line where you are executing the thread in real..But what is it doing? 

As told by you in comment
*It is just a simple CSV file parser using opencsv that implements the Callable interface and has the parsing logic in the call method that it overrides.* 
And you are making the threads to execute in sequence rather than parallel. Moreover, 
the real IO is done in following code:
Iterator it = arrayList.iterator();

```
while(it.hasNext()){
doc = createDocument(file_name,it.next());
try{
    //somefunction(doc);
    }catch(Exception e){}
```

I think `createDocument` is the one with exhaustive IO bound operation . And this method is executed Sequentially rather  than in parallel by each thread.

Comment: I asked exactly the same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456002/parallel-processing-of-files-in-java-with-executorservice-does-not-use-all-of-th/17456049#comment25362724_17456002

Y U NO GIVES US YOUR CODE?

Comment: @pavelrappo +1 TO your that comment and this one too..:)

Comment: @pavelrappo: Sorry about that.. It's just a simple parsing code using opencsv. I have edited my post to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

As already posted, be sure that the processing happens in your threads, not in the single dispatching thread. I'd try this relatively simple solution:

- Give each thread a `File` object to work on. This ensures that the actual work is done in each thread and also that you have a limited number of open files. (If you passed an `InputStream` to the threads for example, then you'd have all files open at once. By passing `File`s, you'll have only as many open files as the maximum number of concurrent threads.)
- Let it use a `BufferedReader` or a `BufferedInputStream` with a large buffer, something like 1-4MB. This makes your application read big blocks at a time, which is much more efficient than multiple threads reading small pieces and the hard disk head constantly seeking. Hopefully your OS will schedule such reads so that they don't occur simultaneously.
- Dispatch them using an `ExecutorService`, possibly with a number slightly larger than the number of your processors, so that if some thread is blocked by IO, there are enough others that work (if there is work for them, of course).

So the result could look something like this:

```
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
final int bufSize = 1024*1024;

// prepare tasks
List<Callable<List<MyObj>>> tasks
    = new ArrayList<Callable<List<MyObj>>>();
for(final File file : files)
    tasks.add(new Callable<List<MyObj>>() {
        public List<MyObj> call() throws Exception {
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(
                    new BufferedInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(file), bufSize)
                );
            try {
                // do processing
            } finally {
                r.close();
            }
        }
    });

// run them
int threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 2;
List<Future<List<MyObj>>> results
    = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount).invokeAll(tasks);
```

If it turns out that processing is the bottleneck, instead of disk IO, you could further speed up your parser slightly by using `java.nio`.

(Note: I only sketched the code, I haven't tried to compile it.)